# Create SPL staking on Solana Ecosystem

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli, anchor-solana, solana-program-library

I'm newbie in programming, so the questiong is: is there any guides how i can create staking pool on solana ecosystem for created token? And what is the steps?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

By staking, I assume you mean liquidity mining.

You can plug in quarry -- https://github.com/QuarryProtocol/quarry and use their already existing program to create a new liquidity pool